# Measure Theoretic Justification For Manipulating Conditional Probability of Events Given a Continuous Random Variable and an Event

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution, measure-theory

When considering the conditional probability of an event given a continuous random variable (or vector) can you essentially just manipulate the probability as if you were only working with discrete random variables/events with positive probability? 
This question was prompted while going over a proof from the textbook of a graduate probability course I took for Rényi's results on the order statistics of exponential. If all the random variables in the proof were discrete I would be perfectly satisfied with the explanation but I don't know how to justify it for continuous random variables / in a broader measure theoretic framework. The proof goes as follows: 
Suppose $X_1,\dots, X_n \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathrm{Expo}(1)$ then consider
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(X_{(2)} - X_{(1)} > t| X_{(1)} \right) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left(X_{(2)} - X_{(1)} > t| X_{(1)}, X_{(1)} = X_i \right) \mathbb{P}\left(X_{(1)} = X_i | X_{(i)} \right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(X_{(2)} - X_{(1)} > t| X_{(1)}, X_{(1)} = X_1 \right) 
\end{align}
And for an arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{P}\left(X_{(2)} - a > t| X_{(1)} = a, X_{(1)} = X_1 \right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(X_{2} - a > t, \dots,  X_{n} - a > t| X_{1} = a, X_{2} > a, \dots, X_{n} > a \right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(X_{2} - a > t, \dots,  X_{n} - a > t| X_{2} > a, \dots, X_{n} > a \right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(X_{2} - a > t,| X_{2} > a \right) \dots \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n} - a > t,| X_{n} > a \right)  \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(X_{2} - a > t,| X_{2} > a \right)^{n-1} \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(X_{2} > t \right)^{n-1}
\end{align}

I intuitively understand what is going on in this proof and I would accept it completely if the random variables were discrete however I cannot prove why this works for continuous random variables even though it feels like it all should.
I have read the chapters in Durrett's and Olaf Kallenberg's textbooks on conditional expectation and conditional probability given a Sigma field and I still can't understand the justification for this or how this would be proved. 
I have the following specific questions from the proof:

1. Is there a sort of law of total probability for conditional probability given a continuous random variable? 
   The first step of the proof seems to rely on what appears to be a law of total probability by for the conditional probability of an event given a continuous random variable. In other words if $\{B_i\}$ are a partition of $\Omega$ then
   \begin{align*}
       \mathbb{P}(A|X) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A|X, B_i) \mathbb{P}(B_i|X)
   \end{align*}
   I have been struggling with how to figure out how to prove or disprove this as I know that when you condition on a continuous random variable $\mathbb{P}(\cdot|X)$ is not actually necessarily a probability measure but the above still seems plausible.
2. What does it even mean to condition on both a continuous random variable and an event with positive probability? 
   After much thought I realize I do not understand what the expression  $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{(2)} - X_{(1)} > t| X_{(1)}, X_{(1)} = X_1 \right)$ represents since we are conditioning on $X_1$ but also taking the event $X_{(1)} = X_1$ as true.
   More generally is the expression $\mathbb{P}\left(A|X, B\right)$ where $A$ and $B$ are events even well defined? Or would it be more precise to say it should only ever be $\mathbb{P}(A|X=x, B)$ (which I believe is equivalent to $\mathbb{P})(A|X=x, I_B=1)$)  or $\mathbb{P}(A|X, I_B)$ as we are technically taking the conditional expectation of $I_A$ with respect to the Sigma field $\sigma(X, I_B)$? 
   It seems to me you could argue that $\mathbb{P}(A|X, I_B)$ is the unique a.s. $\sigma(X, I_B)$ measurable function $f(X, I_B) = \mathbb{P}(A|X, I_B)$ such that it meets the properties of a conditional expectation. And in this frame work we have following things being equivalent.
   \begin{align}
   \mathbb{P}(A|X=x, I_B=1) = f(x, 1) = \mathbb{P}(A|X=x, B)
   \end{align}
   However I am not confident in this and it has been quite confusing to me and I would appreciate any resources on the matter as there seems to be a lot of notational ambiguity about what exactly it means when you condition on both a continuous random variable and an event.
3. Why is the following conditioning equivalent 
   There is a step in the proof that essentially appears to rely on the following equivalence of events below:
   \begin{align}
   \{X_{(1)} = a \cap X_{(1)} = X_1\} = \{X_{1} = a \cap X_2 >a \cap \dots \cap X_n > a\}
   \end{align}
   If everything was discrete then I would agree the probability of something conditionied on either of the events would be equal. But why does that still work when the events are measure zero? Is the idea something like the Sigma fields they generate are the same - i.e.
   \begin{align*}
   \sigma(X_1, I_{X_{(1)} = X_1}) = \sigma(X_1, I_{X_2 >X_1} ,\dots, I_{X_n >X_1} )
   \end{align*}
   and thus the conditional expectations are equivalent?
4. What Justifies Dropping the conditioning on $X_1 = a$ 
   Again if $X_i$ were all discrete then $\mathbb{P}(X_2 > a+t|X_1=a, X_2 > a) = \mathbb{P}(X_2 > a+t)$ is obvious because the events are independent. But why does that still work when they are continuous?

Any resources or textbooks that deal with these questions in a measure theoretic way specifically would be greatly appreciated as well!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Could you cite your source of the derivation? It would be appreciable also to trim down the post as it seems there are currently 4 questions here (I am not saying these are different though).

Comment: The question needs to be condensed.  A shorter version that focuses a very specific question has a better chance to get a good answer.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I can't give the textbook citation as its currently unpublished/only used by the professor for this class. Regarding the length, I was worried it was too long. I will try posting the questions separately instead.